# Is it possible to search for multiple terms with rgrep?

Tags: rgrep

Here is a minimal example:

File `example.org` has the following content:

```
Music and Poetry
```

After doing `M-x rgrep`, when prompted "search for", if I type: `music and poetry`, rgrep will find `example.org`.

But now if I put `poetry music` or even `music poetry` in "search for", rgrep doesn't find anything...

I also tried `poetry|music`, `-e poetry -e music` and `'poetry|music'`, with no result.

Is there a way to ask rgrep to retrieve files containing the terms `poetry` AND `music`?

Comment: `M-x rgrep` invokes the `grep` utility.  You can use `M-x man RET grep` to read about the regexp syntax supported by `grep`.  (Conveniently, the default BRE regexp syntax has a lot in common with Emacs regexps.)

Comment: `grep` matching is line-based, though.  The regexp must match single lines, so if you need to find files with *both* `poetry` and `music` then they would generally need to be on the same line as each other (unless your `grep` supports the `-z` option which would effectively treat non-binary files as a single line).

Comment: IOW, use `poetry\|music`.

Comment: It seems that `poetry\|music` is equivalent to `music` OR `poetry`

Comment: Sorry I've misunderstood (multiple times). Undaunted, I suggest `poetry.*music\|music.*poetry`.  I don't know of an easier way to specify `AND`: this says "`poetry` followed by anything followed by `music` OR `music` followed by anything followed by `poetry`. Heed @phils's comment about the line-oriented nature of `grep`.

Comment: Thank you, `poetry.*music\|music.*poetry` worked well. I find it strange that they implemented `OR` and not `AND` though...

Comment: I believe it has to do with the origin of regexes. In mathematical computation theory, there is a class of languages called `regular` which are recognized/generated by `regular expressions`. Those include alternation (`OR`) but not the kind of `AND` that you want here. Modern regexes are designed for pattern matching convenience and are extensions of the original `regular expressions` which have nice mathematical properties that allow you to prove things easily. But some limitations persist. OTOH, `AND` is implemented in most search engines nowadays, so using an Emacs package that is built...

Comment: ... on top of one of those search engines would make things easier in this case. But regexes are adequate for the vast majority of searches. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages) for some background.